# Getting Blank Date as string from a custom date method

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, pattern-matching

I am making a date filter for which I have created a custom method for date to be parse in specific date format.
I have date with to two formats dd MMM yyyy & yyyy-mm-dd which is passed in a single method to be parse and return in format of yyyy-mm-dd. **As I have a complex structure at end both type of formatted string will go under the date parsing method.**

ISSUE:: I am getting a blank string as return from this method when format is in yyyy-mm-dd. please provide me inputs of where i am wrong. Below is the code

```
 //fetching date from methods
String current_date=CurrentFilterPeriod.dateParsing("2017-04-02");
String prev_date=CurrentFilterPeriod.dateParsing("01 Apr 2017");




//singleton file for date filter method
public class CurrentFilterPeriod {
    private static Calendar cal = getInstance();
    private static Date current_date = cal.getTime();

    //defined formats for date
    private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    private static SimpleDateFormat formatterString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");



//method for parsing date
public static String dateParsing(String date){
    Date newDate;
    String returnDate = "";
    if (date.equals(formatter.toPattern())){
        returnDate=date;
    }
    Log.e("DB","date===>"+date);
    try {
        newDate = formatter.parse(date);
        Log.e("DB","New Date===>"+newDate);
        returnDate=formatterString.format(newDate);
        Log.e("DB","returnDate===>"+returnDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return returnDate;
}

}
```

**RESULT:: current_date=""    prev_date="2017-04-01"**

I am stuck here please help me or tell me other methods to get by desired output.**Want result in format of yyyy-mm-dd**

Comment: the method retun current_date null and you need it to return formatted date like this yyyy-mm-dd???

Comment: When I run your code, I get a stacktrace from a `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-04-02"`. If you had not seen this stacktrace or this exception on your computer, you have a serious flaw in your project setup which is hiding vital information about errors from you. If so, I recommend you fix your setup first thing, before searching for a solution to how you get the desired output from your program. :-) Also on my computer your log statements *are* printing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want result format like: `yyyy-mm-dd`. You need to check your Date String with `formatterString` formatter.

Change your code with:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

boolean isValidDate(String input) {
     try {
          format.parse(input);
          return true;
     }
     catch(ParseException e){
          return false;
     }
}
```

Now call the method using:

```
//method for parsing date
public static String dateParsing(String date) {
 Date newDate;
 String returnDate = "";
 if (isValidDate(date)) {
  returnDate = date;
  return returnDate;
 } else {
  Log.e("DB", "date===>" + date);
  try {
   newDate = formatter.parse(date);
   Log.e("DB", "New Date===>" + newDate);
   returnDate = formatterString.format(newDate);
   Log.e("DB", "returnDate===>" + returnDate);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 return returnDate;
}
```